# Craft 3: Search in 15000 entries

Tags: search

I have a low-budget project where would like to migrate an academic website to Craft. The website contains 15000 proverbs about women in different cultures that can be searched, (http://www.womeninproverbsworldwide.com/the-proverbs/search/index.php).

I consider making each proverb an entry. Will search perform fast enough with 15000 entries or should I consider a different approach?

Thank you for sharing your opinion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft can handle such an amount of elements really well but you could get in trouble when you are going to import them all at once without changing your web server config or using certain importers since it will extend the defaults max_execution_time. So you'll have to import them step by step or via queue (or via import plugin).

I created a job center with about 60.000 elements currently and everything works smooth

Comment: That's a good tip about importing, thanks Robin.